# Wordpress $GET Shortcode issues

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I need to insert some markup inside page based on whether a URL Query Var exists or not. I'm trying to insert the code inside a shortcode like so:

```
//Create Shortcode for join page error message
add_shortcode( 'join_error', 'av_join_error' );
function av_join_error(){
    $joinresult = $_GET["result"];
    if($joinresult){
        echo "<p class='alert'>Your payment was declined. Please double check your details and try again.</p>";
    }
}
```

It's not working, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is mostly fine, you will need to post more.

First do `print_r($_GET)` and make sure the array is actually being set.

Also, shortcodes should always **return** and not **echo.** Using return keeps the shortcode output where it is in the document/page (echo will output it to the top).

more about that here under Output: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply **jsnrgnt**. Doing a print_r of $_GET returns an array, however my PHP skill aren't good enough to get inside and pick it apart. Any more info would be great.

Comment: @gurtfrobe, the PHP manual [is your friend](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) (the Codex too), most of the times you'll find working examples there. Don't forget to use `isset()`, so your code won't dump PHP notices (with WP_DEBUG enabled, which is best practice on dev environments).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//Create Shortcode for join page error message

function av_join_error(){
    $joinresult = $_GET["result"];
    if($joinresult){
        echo "<p class='alert'>Your payment was declined. Please double check your details and try again.</p>";
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'join_error', 'av_join_error' );
```